# Como resolver o erro " PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Classes\Fabrica\FabricaPessoa" not found"

Tags: php, namespace

Não estou conseguindo entender o motivo pelo qual está dando esse erro, parece ser algo bobo, mas não consigo resolver de forma alguma.

Primeiramente gostaria de pedir desculpas se ficou um pouco confuso ou mal explicado, sou iniciante na área e essa é minha primeira postagem no stackoverflow. Desde já agradeço a disponibilidade e compreensão.

Em uma pasta chamada "Classes" criei os arquivos "Pessoa.php" e "Cachorro.php", ambos contento suas respectivas classes, dentro dessa pasta também criei a pasta "Fabrica", contento os arquivos "FabricaPessoa.php" e "FabricaCachorro.php" os quais suas classes contém um método estático para retornar uma instância da classe Pessoa e da classe Cachorro. Eu então importo as classes "Fabrica" para o arquivo "index.php" (o qual eu executo no meu shell) e o VSCode as reconhece, sem apontar qualquer erro. Mas ao executar retorna o seguinte :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Classes\Fabrica\FabricaPessoa" not found in /var/www/html/b2b/code_training/php_test/factory/index.php:10
```

A seguir esta o código referente a cada arquivo:

index.php :

```
<?php

// include "vendor/autoload.php";

use Classes\Fabrica\FabricaPessoa as Pessoa;
use Classes\Fabrica\FabricaCachorro as FabricaCachorro;

try {
    $pessoa = Pessoa::getPessoa('Arthur', 'Gonçalves');
    $cachorro = FabricaCachorro::getCachorro('Dora', 'Pitbull'); 
    echo $pessoa->nomeCompleto() . "\n";
    echo $cachorro->latir();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Pessoa.php :

```
<?php

namespace Classes;

class Pessoa
{
    public String $nome;
    public String $sobrenome;
    public $nascimento;


    public function nomeCompleto()
    {
        return "$this->nome $this->sobrenome";
    }

    public function __construct(mixed $values)
    {
        switch (count($values)) {
            case 1:
                echo "Erro";
                break;
            case 3:
                $this->nascimento = $values[2];
            case 2:
                $this->nome = $values[0];
                $this->sobrenome = $values[1];
                break;
            default:
                echo "Erro";
        }
    }

    public function getNascimento()
    {
        return $this->nascimento;
    }
}
```

Cachorro.php :

```
<?php

namespace Classes;

class Cachorro
{
    public $nome;
    public $raca;
    public $nascimento;

    public function __construct(mixed $values)
    {
        switch (count($values)) {
            case 1:
                echo "Erro";
                break;
            case 3:
                $this->nascimento = $values[2];
            case 2:
                $this->nome = $values[0];
                $this->raca = $values[1];
                break;
            default:
                echo "Erro";
        }
    }

    public function latir()
    {
        echo "Au Au meu nome é $this->nome";
    }
}
```

FabricaPessoa.php:

```
<?php

namespace Classes\Fabrica;

use Classes\Pessoa;

class FabricaPessoa
{
    public static function getPessoa(mixed $values)
    {
        $pessoa = new Pessoa($values);
        return $pessoa;
    }
}
```

FabricaCachorro.php:

```
<?php

namespace Classes\Fabrica;

use Classes\Cachorro;

class FabricaCachorro
{
    public static function getCachorro(mixed $values)
    {
        $cachorro = new Cachorro($values);
        return $cachorro;
    }
}
```

Os arquivos e pastas :

[image: percebam que tentei utilizar o autoloader do composer também, mas não funcionou, também utilizei namespaces mas sem sucesso]

Comment: O erro diz que a classe não foi encontrada. E realmente, você não as incluiu no seu arquivo. Tente adicionar em seu index.php, `require './classes/Fabrica/FabricaPessoa.php'`. Isso fará com que exista a classe `FabricaPessoa`, mas ainda vão faltar as outras, mas ai é só incluí-las da mesma forma.

Comment: @andre_luiss pensei que utilizar namespace poderia substituir a necessidade do require, agradeço à ajuda ! Mais uma dúvida. Caso eu inclua as classes no meu index não é necessário que eu inclua a classe "Pessoa" dentro de "FabricaPessoa" correto ? Pois ambas estão importadas no index. No entanto seria válido eu importar "Pessoa" para dentro de "FabricaPessoa" e chamar apenas "FabricaPessoa" no index?

Comment: Você não precisa importar ela duas vezes, e se tentar, vai até dar erro. Ai cabe a você definir como achar melhor organizar, importando dentro de Pessoa, ou dentro do index. No meu caso, eu escolheria importar os arquivos um a um no index. Acho que fica mais organizado. Mas ai, é somente minha opinião, não sei te dizer se é a melhor forma....

Answer (score 1):

### Require ou Include

Você precisa adicionar requires ou includes no index.php do projeto para cada arquivo que for instanciar:

```
require "./classes/Fabrica/FabricaPessoa.php";
```

### Autoload

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Ou se quiser utilizar um padrão mais avançado de projeto, pode seguir os padrões PSR-4 e utilizar autoload.

Falando de uma forma bem "rústica", um autoload faz o trabalho de "automatizar os includes" de acordo com os caminhos dos namespaces.

E os arquivos só serão carregados sem require ou include no index se tiver autoload no projeto e utilizar namespaces condizentes com o caminho das pastas e arquivos dando atenção para letras maiúsculas. Ex:

Classe no caminho Classes/Fabrica/Pessoa

```
<?php

namespace Classes/Fabrica;

class Pessoa { ...
```

E chamando no index

```
...
require "autoload.php";

use Classes\Fabrica\Pessoa;

$pessoa = new Pessoa();
...
```

É possivel implementar o próprio autoload no projeto utilizando funções do php, como esta: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.autoload.php

Ou se já está familiarizado com o Composer, o package de autoload padrão que vem na instalação do composer já faz praticamente todo o trabalho para você.
Existem diversos tutoriais na internet, inclusive no youtube ensinando a configurar e utilizar.

### Resumindo

Utilize require, ou require_once (para garantir uma única chamada do arquivo) no seu index para todos os arquivos. Ou então utilize padrões mais avançados como autoload recomendados pelo padrão PSR-4.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Vi que está utilizando o *"vendor/autoload.php"*, ou seja está utilizando o composer, nesse caso você está utilizando o autoload, de acordo com a psr-4

primeiro passo seria verificar seu arquivo *composer.json*:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Classes\\" : "classes/"
        }
    }
}
```

no terminal deve ser rodado os comandos (por garantia) `composer-install`, após o processo rodar: `composer-dump autoload -o`

Em seguida fiz alguns ajustes de exemplo para "ajustar" seu código em relação à sua dúvida. Descomente a linha onde vc faz o require do vendor/autoload.php

**index.php**

```
<?php

// ini_set('display_erros', 1);
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Classes\Fabrica\FabricaPessoa as Pessoa;
use Classes\Fabrica\FabricaCachorro as FabricaCachorro;

try {
    $pessoa = Pessoa::getPessoa('Arthur', 'Gonçalves');
    $cachorro = FabricaCachorro::getCachorro('Dora', 'Pitbull');
    echo $pessoa->nomeCompleto() . "<br>";
    echo $cachorro->latir();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

**FabricaPessoa.php**

```
<?php

namespace Classes\Fabrica;

use Classes\Pessoa;

class FabricaPessoa
{
    public static function getPessoa(...$values)
    {
        $pessoa = new Pessoa(...$values);
        return $pessoa;
    }
}
```

**FabricaCachorro.php**

```
<?php

namespace Classes\Fabrica;

use Classes\Cachorro;

class FabricaCachorro
{
    public static function getCachorro(...$values)
    {
        $cachorro = new Cachorro(...$values);
        return $cachorro;
    }
}
```

**Pessoa.php**

```
<?php

namespace Classes;

class Pessoa
{
    public string $nome;
    public string $sobrenome;
    public $nascimento;


    public function nomeCompleto()
    {
        return "$this->nome $this->sobrenome";
    }

    public function __construct(...$values)
    {
        switch (count($values)) {
            case 1:
                echo "Erro";
                break;
            case 3:
                $this->nascimento = $values[2];
            case 2:
                $this->nome = $values[0];
                $this->sobrenome = $values[1];
                break;
            default:
                echo "Erro";
        }
    }

    public function getNascimento()
    {
        return $this->nascimento;
    }
}
```

**Cachorro.php**

```
<?php

namespace Classes;

    class Cachorro
    {
        public $nome;
        public $raca;
        public $nascimento;
    
        public function __construct(...$values)
        {
            switch (count($values)) {
                case 1:
                    echo "Erro";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $this->nascimento = $values[2];
                case 2:
                    $this->nome = $values[0];
                    $this->raca = $values[1];
                    break;
                default:
                    echo "Erro";
            }
        }
    
        public function latir()
        {
            echo "Au Au meu nome é $this->nome";
        }
    }
```

Nas funções eu passei o `...` para compactar e descompactar argumentos passados, é como se você não declarasse a quantidade de argumentos que você vai passar, e pode depois fazer por exemplo o `func_get_args()`

o vendor autoload é justamente pra não precisar fazer o include/require dos arquivos, ele mesmo se encarrega de mapear, desde que tenha a raiz de cada namespace declarada ele consegue ir em mais níveis a partir deste.

Espero que tenha ajudado!